# Adding a Second Wired Router Breaks WiFi

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I have a Virgin Media cable modem with 4 Ethernet ports. I need more Ethernet ports, so I've got a second router - a TP-Link TL-R460 cable router/modem - and disabled its DHCP, then connected one of its LAN Ethernet ports (not the WAN port) to one of the LAN ports on the Virgin Media router.

The result is that the devices connected to the second router seem to access the Internet just fine, as do devices connected to the primary modem router with Ethernet cables.

However, devices connecting to the Virgin Media modem router over WiFi do not have Internet access. The WiFi signal indicator displays an exclamation mark and the status is displayed as "Internet not available".

As I said, I've disabled DHCP on the secondary router and it doesn't seem to have a NAT feature to disable.

I can't work out what's causing this problem. The secondary router doesn't have WiFi at all. I've tried to find tutorials for adding a secondary wired router but almost every tutorial I find is about adding a second wireless router to extend range, and that's not what I'm trying to do.

### Update

In response to comments, I've posted `IPCONFIG` and `ARP -A` output below for three clients. I've redacted the MACs for security reasons but can provide more detail if necessary.

One thing that I've noticed doing this testing is that the loss of Internet access on the wireless clients is intermittent. Sometimes it doesn't work at all (e.g. error on Android is `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` when loading a web page), but sometimes it works very slowly and sometimes seems fairly normal.

Wired client (Windows 10) connected to Master router
=======================================
IP: 192.168.0.17
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1

ARP Info:
Interface: 192.168.0.17 --- 0x5
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.0.1           48-d3-43-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.10          4c-0b-be-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.12          00-0e-58-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.13          00-0e-58-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.14          b8-e9-37-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.15          00-0e-58-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.16          58-19-f8-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.19          00-24-8c-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.20          00-0e-58-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.22          40-b8-9a-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.23          94-9f-3e-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.25          a4-77-33-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.26          48-d6-d5-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.30          70-56-81-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-xx-xx-xx     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-xx-xx-xx     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-xx-xx-xx     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-0xx-xx-xx     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-xx-xx-xx     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
==========================================================


Wireless client (MacBook) connected to Master router
==========================================
IP: 192.168.0.30
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1

ARP Info:
? (192.168.0.1) at 48:d3:43:00:00:00 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.17) at 9c:5c:8e:00:00:00 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.19) at 0:24:8c:00:00:00 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.22) at 40:b8:9a:00:00:00 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.25) at a4:77:33:00:00:00 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.26) at 48:d6:d5:00:00:00 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:00:00:00 on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:00:00:00 on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
==========================================================


Wired client (Windows 10) connected to Secondary router
==========================================
IP: 192.168.0.19
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1

ARP Info:
Interface: 192.168.0.19 --- 0x3
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.0.1           48-d3-43-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.12          00-0e-58-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.13          00-0e-58-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.14          b8-e9-37-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.15          00-0e-58-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.17          9c-5c-8e-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.20          00-0e-58-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.22          40-b8-9a-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.23          94-9f-3e-xx-xx-xx     dynamic
  192.168.0.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-xx-xx-xx     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-xx-xx-xx     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-xx-xx-xx     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-xx-xx-xx     static
  235.162.134.156       01-00-5e-xx-xx-xx     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-xx-xx-xx     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
==========================================================

Comment: Maybe the second router does have the same IP as the first one? Please post IP/Default Gateway and DNS of a working LAN client, and a non working Wifi client.

Comment: That, _and_ please post the ARP cache (`arp -a` or `ip neigh` or such).

Comment: I've posted the output in the updated question. Hope this helps - thanks!